# Considerations for forecasting

Tags: time-series, forecasting, accuracy

I am trying to make a generic forecaster for many short (~14 points) to long term (~365 points) time series data assuming the seasonal period to be weekly. The predictions are going to be made for a streaming input so I will have to automate most parts. The way I am approaching now is to loop through a bunch of time series models and pick the best one based on AIC.

1. Probably, that is not the best idea but I am starting out with this. Could you please suggest what other considerations/approaches should I take?
2. Some of the data is just too random without much seasonality or trends. Should I skip forecasting them? If so, how should I decide?
3. What would be the best way to evaluate the predictions considering I have pretty large number(~100000) of datasets I am working with.

Comment: And then I find [this](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/aic/). So I am a bit lost now.

Comment: I'd suggest comparing relative probabilities exp((AICmin − AICi)/2) instead of plain AICs -- see [AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion). Could you post some of these rel probs for your data ?